# IScorable only when no conversation is active

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a bot using luis but as luis often takes 2-3 seconds to respond I have implemented an `IScorable` that uses simple regex patterns to match common requests that dont need to go through luis (hello, what are you etc.).

My issue is that when the user is in a child dialog or a prompt is awaiting user input the scorable is still run which can result in the following:

> User: Hello
>
> Bot: Hi 
>   (from scorable)
>
> User: What time is my flight?

```
PromptDialog.Text(context, LookupFlightNumber, "What is your flight number?");
```

> Bot: What is your flight number?

In the above example the users next message will be sent to the `LookupFlightNumber` method but if the user said "hello" the scorable would match and the bot would say hello.

In the scorable I had tried to return `false` in the `HasScore` override when the `IDialogStack` had more than 1 frame but the frame count  doesnt seem to be what I expected.

**Update:**
I have moved the logic from the Scorable into the `RootDialog.MessageReceived` as an alternative but am still interested if it would be possible with an `IScorable`